# Having trouble in forcing text in text area to start from extreme left end in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

If I place cursor accidentally earlier in the text area, it starts writing from there leaving some spaces in the beginning which I don't want. I want to force it to start from extreme left like it does in input boxes. Here's the code and attached screenshot for reference :

```html
<label>Post your query below!</label>
<textarea class="sidebar_area" id="sender_query" placeholder="Write your [enter image description here][1]query here! " rows="4" cols="23">
        </textarea>

<button type="submit" class="send_button" id="send_button">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure there is no space between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` tags

```
<textarea class="sidebar_area" id="sender_query" placeholder="Write your [enter image 
description here][1]query here! " rows="4" cols="23"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

Remove empty space between `<textarea></textarea>`

```html
<label>Post your query below!</label>
<textarea class="sidebar_area" id="sender_query" rows="4" cols="23"></textarea>

<button type="submit" class="send_button" id="send_button">Send</button>
```

Comment: There is no need to remove placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is exactly the same, then your problem is the empty space between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`. Inside the textarea tag you can set the textarea content, which now you basically set to a couple of spaces (that's also why your placeholder is not shown). So replace

```
<textarea class="sidebar_area" id="sender_query" placeholder="Write your [enter image description here][1]query here! " rows="4" cols="23">
    </textarea>
```

with

```
<textarea class="sidebar_area" id="sender_query" placeholder="Write your [enter image description here][1]query here! " rows="4" cols="23"></textarea>
```